# FlatPlat Broke My System

Tags: gnome

I'm new to the Linux world.Just installed yesterday.I successfully downloaded and applied the Flatplat theme, but my computer is stuck on the splash screen after rebooting.How can I reset my theme back to normal?

Comment: Just reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: I would suggest waiting on customizations until you understand the defaults...and how to install software and customize safely. The power of Linux is that you get to see the sausage getting made, and can rework the gears any way you wish...but that means you can break the system, too.